# Travel to South Korea with a German residence permit (but less than 6 months)

Tags: visas, south-korea, permits, german-residents, indonesian-citizens

I am a foreigner from Indonesia and living in Germany. I want to travel to South Korea in April 2019 (only for 7 days) and would like therefore to apply a tourist visa. I have checked all the requirements on the official website and I can fulfil them, e.g. passport, bank account, etc. I have even bought a two-way ticket, as required for the visa application. However, I just realized and now I am not sure whether the validity of my German residence permit (which is less than 6 months, namely 4.5 months on the departure date) would be a problem. Do you have any similar experience?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need a visa? German residents are exempt in some circumstances https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: @Traveller: Yes I need a visa.

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer my question.

I was granted a visa and was travelling to South Korea.
The officer did not ask specifically about the validity of my German residence permit but was focussing on my bank account and was asking whether I have been living in Germany for more than 2 years (because this is one of the requirements for Indonesian citizens who want to apply a Korean Visa from Germany).
For this, the officer asked me to show the copy of my previous German residence permit (note that I always got a card as a residence permit rather than a paper sticking on my passport and that card must be returned when I have a new card). I could not show this proof because I never made a copy of that card.
However, it is not a big deal since the officer can check it from my passport (e.g. arrival date, return date, etc.).

However, at that time, I also showed the officer a letter of employment stated that I have been staying since 2015.
Hopefully, my experience helps!